# Unordered list with boxes

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list where the list items are displayed horizontally. Each list item should contain some text and images. When I add content to them the list item is no longer aligned.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>222</li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Jsbin: https://jsbin.com/fobopayaco/edit?html,css,output

Is there som css I can add to fix this? Or should I change my markup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just set `vertical-align` to `top` for example

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>222</li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

By adding text, you're seeing the effects of the default `vertical-align` property: your list-items are being aligned to the baseline.

If you want them all to be aligned in the same spot, specify a `vertical-align` property for all of them:

```
li{
  border:1px solid blue;
  display:inline-block;
  height:100px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The list just doesn't like empty items. If you need an item to be empty for some reason use `<li>&nbsp;</li>`, otherwise once you add content to all items normalcy will return.

Answer (score 0):

Try `float:left` on li instead of `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `float` to `left` for every `<li>`

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>222</li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add float :left or  display:inline in your css

```
    li{
      border:1px solid blue;
      display:inline-block;
      height:100px;
      width:100px;  
     display:inline;
    }
```

and here is working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/5dh2ak3a/